# Windows Virtual PC RC: running VPC 2007 images

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Simple question: Can Windows Virtual PC for Windows 7 run VPC 2007 images?

Comment: Isn't that even the same version?

Comment: @Ivo - No it's not Virtual PC 2007 is for XP/Vista. Windows Virtual PC is rewritten and only works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The disk images work fine, but you will have to create a new configuration file.  Just do this by using the Create Virtual Machine wizard.  When it gets to the part about hard drive settings, tell it to use your existing VHD file.

Comment: I can back this up. I have just installed all the RC Virtual PC related software for Windows 7. I had to update my 7 images to work with a new config file it was simple and quick -- seeing Microsoft Bob running in  Windows 7 is almost as funny as seeing Microsoft Bob running in Windows Vista. Ah Bob...the punch-line that will continue to give me joy for at least another 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V and Virtual PC RC both run them perfectly. The few I have tested so far it has run without any hitches apart from upgrading the integration tools.

However I have not tried differential disks as this changed in Hyper-V/Virtual PC.

**Hyper-V images can NOT be run on Virtual PC. There is also no backwards compatibility once opened in the new Virtual PC**

Comment: So, I can run VPC 2007 images in WVPC RC, but once a VPC 2007 image has been run in RC it can no longer run under VPC 2007?

Comment: Correct. In some cases it does work but it is not guaranteed until RTM.